# In the Android emulator, is it possible to notice vibration effects?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Quite a simple question. Is it possible to notice vibrations in the Android emulator?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I guess you want to know if vibration happened ? If that is so then look into the logcat in the emulator for the vibration message

Comment: Yeah I guess this is the only way then, was hoping to have a visual indication. Thanks anyway

Comment: what exactly should be in logcat that says vibration happened?

Comment: Also refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/43225706/846727 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/3029804/846727

Comment: Would bè cool to have an app that shows visually the vibrations, like the phones that are made for deaf people, and that shows a light.

Comment: Something like hapticfeedback.vibrate?