# How to check if vibration happened, in logcat?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I searched in the web but i couldn find a single article dealing in a straight forward way on how to find the vibrate on/off logs in logcat. If anybody who is aware of the procedure, please enlighten me. Once again i need it specifically to check if my app triggers vibrator or not...

Answer (score 2):

**Vibration data is not logged by default.**  Fortunately, there is some code in [HardwareServices.java](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=services/java/com/android/server/HardwareService.java;h=88074c2c59eab371b5d3022dc6c90bb187df1d7c;hb=HEAD) that can be enabled to provide exactly what you want.  Keep in mind that since this is part of the framework, changing it will require you to  [rebuild](http://source.android.com/source/building-dream.html) and reflash your device.  If you are running on an ADP or the emulator this should be easy.  It might be a bit more challenging if you are doing this on another device.

Locate the following code and replace `false` with `true` and you should be all set.

```
        if (false) {
            String s = "";
            int N = pattern.length;
            for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
                s += " " + pattern[i];
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "vibrating with pattern: " + s);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim...how can i find this hardwareservices.java?

Comment: It is available from the [Android Open Source Project](http://source.android.com/source/download.html).

Comment: any idea why this is hard-coded to false? and not a setting somewhere?