# In the Android Emulator, how to know if vibration happened?

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator

I launch my app on emulator device by command: react-native run-android.
I use the Vibration API in my app, how to check if vibration happened ?

Thanks.

Comment: have u checked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2704544/4239410. Look into the comments also.

Comment: i checked it, but i can't find logcat of android emulator in react-native

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In the Android emulator, is it possible to notice vibration effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703679/in-the-android-emulator-is-it-possible-to-notice-vibration-effects)

Answer (score 0):

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703679/in-the-android-emulator-is-it-possible-to-notice-vibration-effects/2704544#2704544) answer you can look for the vibration message in the logcat, you can use `logcat -b system` command

Answer (score 0):

check logcat in the emulator it gives vibration message